# C# dll method not available in C# but available in VB

Tags: c#

I have one project in C# and another one in VB. I use a Kofax dll and i want to call a method to set a field value. I'm actually using Kofax.DBLiteOpt.
In vb I have this implementation for calling a method and setting a value:

```
For Each oDoc As ACDataElement In oDocumentCol 
   If oDoc.AttributeValue("Note") <> "" Then
      oDoc.AttributeValue("Note") = "Value assigned ..."
   End If
Next
```

In C#... I have an error before compiling: ACDataElement does not contain "AttributeValue" definition

```
foreach (ACDataElement oDoc in oDocumentCol)
{
   oDoc.AttributeValue("Note")= "whatever";
}
```

Here is the implementation I see. It has been implemented in C#.

Here is the interface called:

```
namespace Kofax.DBLiteOpt
{
  [Guid("AA7473C3-85D1-46C7-9FB6-5AE29E00EA5D")]
  [CoClass(typeof (ACDataElementClass))]
  [ComImport]
  public interface ACDataElement : _ACDataElement
  {
  }
}
```

And here is _ACDataELement

```
namespace Kofax.DBLiteOpt
{
  [TypeLibType(TypeLibTypeFlags.FHidden | TypeLibTypeFlags.FDual | TypeLibTypeFlags.FNonExtensible | TypeLibTypeFlags.FDispatchable)]
  [Guid("AA7473C3-85D1-46C7-9FB6-5AE29E00EA5D")]
  [ComImport]
  public interface _ACDataElement
  {
    [DispId(1610809359)]
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
    bool AttributeExists([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr), In] string strAttributeName);

    [DispId(1745027079)]
    Collection AttributeNames { [DispId(1745027079), MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)] [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] get; }

    [DispId(0)]
    [IndexerName("AttributeValue")]
    string this[[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr), In] string strAttributeName] { [DispId(0), MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)] [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr), In] set; [DispId(0), MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)] [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] get; }

    ...
}
```

Other note: i decompiled the dll using rider and visual studio in Visual Studio I have this

```
    [DispId(1745027079)]
    Kofax.VBA.Interop.Collection AttributeNames { get; }

    [DispId(0)]
    string this[string strAttributeName] { get; set; }
```

Is there any configuration issue ?

- vb Application targets .NET Framework 4.2, but works also in 4.8
- c# Application targets .NET Framework 4.8, C# version is 8

Is there any reason for behaviour differnce ??
I also tried to use oDoc["Note"] and I do have an error I do not get in vb:

```
System.Exception
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Kofax.Capture.DBLiteOpt: [11012] Kofax.Capture.DBLiteOpt: Cet attribut ne peut pas être mis à jour. (Document, BatchDocGUID)
  Source=KC.CM.Divalto
  Arborescence des appels de procédure :
   à KC.CM.Divalto.Program.Run(String[] args) dans D:\__devs\KC.CM.Divalto\Program.cs :ligne 80
   à KC.CM.Divalto.Program.Main(String[] args) dans D:\__devs\KC.CM.Divalto\Program.cs :ligne 20
```

Error message indicates that i can't update the value using this notation (oDoc["Note"])

Comment: It is a valid in vb.net to name the default property.  But not in C#, you'll have to write `oDoc["Note"]`

Comment: Thanks Hans, it was what I thought at the beginning. but value couldn't be updated in c# while it could in vb.

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to invoke the [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-Us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/) as a method. The correct syntax would be:

```
foreach (ACDataElement oDoc in oDocumentCol)
{
   oDoc["Note"] = "whatever";
}
```

**Update:** Updated according to Hans Passant's comment.

Comment: I also tried it. And it's unsuccessful.

Comment: @davidvera Please define "unsuccessful".

Comment: 'ACDataElement' does not contain a definition for 'AttributeValue' and no accessible extension method 'name' accepting a first argument of type 'type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). I read the documentation and i don't get why: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1061?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS1061)

Comment: @davidvera It would have helped tremendously from the beginning to post what `ACDataElement` actually is because right now, nobody knows.

Comment: I updated the question and provided a sample of the class implementation.